# how to make MPI_Send have processors send in order instead of randomly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to run a program below that uses parallel programming. If we use 4 processors, I want them to contain the sums 1+2=3, 3+4=7, 11, and 15. So I want the sumvector to contain 3, 7, 11, and 15, in that order. HOwever, since MPI_Send has the processors sending in random order, I don't sumvector to contain, say, 7, 15, 3, 11. How can I modify the code below to ensure this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int mynode, totalnodes;
    int sum,startval,endval,accum;
    MPI_Status status;
    int master=3; 

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &totalnodes); // get totalnodes
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &mynode); // get mynode

    sum = 0; // zero sum for accumulation
    vector <int> sumvector;
    startval = 8*mynode/totalnodes+1;
    endval = 8*(mynode+1)/totalnodes;

    for(int i=startval;i<=endval;i=i+1)
        sum=sum+i;
        sumvector.push_back(sum);

    if(mynode!=master)
    {
        MPI_Send(&sum,1,MPI_INT,master,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD); //#9, p.92
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=0;j<totalnodes;j=j+1){
            if (j!=master)
            {
                MPI_Recv(&accum,1,MPI_INT,j,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                printf("processor %d  received from %d\n",mynode, j);
                sum = sum + accum;
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I better off using multithreading instead of MPI?

Comment: You are missing a bunch of includes. And the function declarations have to be available before they are used.

Comment: When you send out the request to get the computation done, include a location where you want the output deposited. When it sends the reply, have it include the location. When you receive the reply, don't just put the result at the next available spot--put it where the location in the reply says it should go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but your current code is equivalent (sans printing what number was received from which rank) to the following one:

```
for(int i=startval;i<=endval;i=i+1)
    sum=sum+i;
sumvector.push_back(sum);

MPI_Reduce(mynode == master ? MPI_IN_PLACE : &sum, &sum, 1, MPI_INT,
           master, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

What you are looking for is either this (the result is gathered by the master rank only):

```
for(int i=startval;i<=endval;i=i+1)
    sum=sum+i;

sumvector.resize(totalnodes);

MPI_Gather(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, &sumvector[0], 1, MPI_INT,
           master, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

or this (results are gathered into all ranks):

```
for(int i=startval;i<=endval;i=i+1)
    sum=sum+i;

sumvector.resize(totalnodes);

MPI_Allgather(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, &sumvector[0], 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Also, the following statement is entirely wrong:

> HOwever, since MPI_Send has the processors sending in random order, I don't sumvector to contain, say, 7, 15, 3, 11.

MPI point-to-point communication requires exactly two things in order to succeed: there must be a *sender* that executes `MPI_Send` **and** a *receiver* that executes a matching `MPI_Recv`. Message reception order could be enforced by simply calling `MPI_Recv` in a loop with increasing source rank, exactly as it is in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this more simply. To start with, you could "gather" the values into a vector on the master process:

```
std::vector <int> sumvector, recvcounts, displs;
startval = 8*mynode/totalnodes+1;
endval = 8*(mynode+1)/totalnodes;

for (int i=0; i<totalnodes; i++)
{
    sumvector.push_back(0);
    recvcounts.push_back(1);
    displs.push_back(i);
}

int myval = startval + endval;
MPI_Gatherv(&myval,
            1,
            MPI_INTEGER,
            &sumvector[0],
            &recvcounts[0],
            &displs[0],
            MPI_INTEGER,
            master,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

which results in sumvector containing:

```
node 0: (0, 0, 0, 0)
node 1: (0, 0, 0, 0)
node 2: (0, 0, 0, 0)
node 3: (3, 7, 11, 15)
```

You could also consider MPI_Allreduce instead. The process would go as follows:

Initialise all vector elements to 0,

```
for (int i=0; i<totalnodes; i++)
{
    sumvector.push_back(0);
}
```

and modify mynode's entry to be the value you want,

```
sumvector[mynode] = startval + endval;
```

Before MPI_Allreduce, the sumvectors contain:

```
node 0: (3, 0, 0, 0)
node 1: (0, 7, 0, 0)
node 2: (0, 0, 11, 0)
node 3: (0, 0, 0, 15)
```

Now, when you sum all of the arrays on each node,

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, 
              &sumvector[0], 
              totalnodes, 
              MPI_INTEGER, 
              MPI_SUM, 
              MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

it results in sumvector containing:

```
node 0: (3, 7, 11, 15)
node 1: (3, 7, 11, 15)
node 2: (3, 7, 11, 15)
node 3: (3, 7, 11, 15)
```

on every node.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing the gather-to-all operation using reduce-to-all with excess zeros?

Comment: To me it wasn't exactly clear what the original poster wished to do in terms of where the summation was performed: i.e. whether locally, or across processes. I wanted to cover both bases with my answer, but yes, the expected output can of course be achieved without the reduce-to-all.